# Comparing two JSON files using jq and keeping the key-value pair from the first file on matching key

Tags: json, yaml, jq

I have these two `json` files and I am trying to find the elements with same `keys` but different `values` using `jq`. Please see expected output for more clarity.

**JSON File 1:**

```
{
  "COMMON-VAR": "ABC",
  "LASTNAME": "D",
  "FIRSTNAME": "JOHN"
}
```

**JSON File 2:**

```
{
  "COMMON-VAR": "DEF",
  "LASTNAME": "S",
  "FIRSTNAME": "JOHN",
  "ADDRESS": "SanJose, CA",
  "ZIP": "09817"
}
```

**Expected output:**

```
{
  "COMMON-VAR": "ABC",
  "LASTNAME": "D",
}
```

Any help/suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For future reference, it is usually a good idea to show some evidence of the research effort you've made, e.g. in the form of an attempt to solve the problem. (See e.g. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: @peak I have attempted this by converting to `yaml` files and using `join` & `yq`. I didn't add my attempt to avoid confusion. `join <(sort file1.yaml) <(sort file2.yaml) | awk '$2!=$3{print $1,$3}' | yq e -I4`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a variant of @oguzismail's perfectly fine answer. Besides using `reduce` constructively rather than using `del`, it is to my eye at least a bit more readable, e.g. with respect to the respective roles of the two files:

```
jq -n '
  input as $f1 | input as $f2
  | reduce ($f1|keys_unsorted[]) as $k ({};
      if $f2 | has($k) and $f1[$k] != $f2[$k] then .[$k]=$f1[$k] else . end)
' file1.json file2.json
```

Answer (score 2):

Iterate over keys of the first object and check whether they exist in the second and have the same value in both objects. Delete those that do, and leave the rest intact.

```
inputs as $a
| reduce keys_unsorted[] as $k (.;
  if ($k | in($a)) and (.[$k] == $a[$k]) then del(.[$k]) else . end
)
```

<sup>[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/N7YaZuWIAZ)</sup>